# Create Trigger by SQL in Liquibase: Error in SQL syntax

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, mariadb, liquibase

I want to create trigger for '`update_time`' and '`deleted_time`' to check the update procedure was Update or Soft remove then assign new value to the specific entity

Here is the `changeSet:`

```
<changeSet id="1694415120381-contract_updateTime_trigger" author="vietdq">
    <sql>
        CREATE TRIGGER updateContractTrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON contract
            FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (OLD.`is_deleted` IS NOT NULL AND NEW.`is_deleted` IS NOT NULL AND OLD.`is_deleted` != NEW.`is_deleted`) THEN
               SET NEW.`deleted_time` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
            ELSE
                SET NEW.`updated_time` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
            END IF;
        END
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

In db,  '`update_time`' and '`deleted_time`' is `DATETIME`

The SQL script works perfectly in SQL file, but in liquibase's changelog file, the exception log just keep inform `check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`

I then split every keyword into row and then found the exception was on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`which made me to change it to `NOW()` ,but i still didnt work.

ANY SOLUTIONNNNN???????

Comment: What is the exception on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: it still informs:"check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9 - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() line

Comment: Mind sharing the version of MariaDB is running too?

Comment: the version of MariaDB is 11.1.2